# Find all categories that have some specific features

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a table containing some categories

```
Categories Table: 
-- category_id   <-- primary key
-- name
```

I also have a table containing some features

```
Features Table: 
-- feature_id   <-- primary key
-- name
```

And the many-to-many relation table:

```
Categories_Features Table: 
-- category_feature_id   <-- primary key
-- category_id
-- feature_id
```

Now I want to find all the categories that have some multiple specific features.
For example all the categories that have both features with id 3 **AND** 10.

Here is the sample query to find all categories that has the feature with id 10:

> select * from categories inner join
>   categories_features
>   on(categories.category_id =
>   categories_features.category_id) where
>   feature_id = 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
SELECT * FROM `categories` 
WHERE
category_id in (select category_id from categories_features where feature_id = 3) 
AND
category_id in (select category_id from categories_features where feature_id = 10)
```